# Why function statement doesn't create a function when using setting it as a method?

Tags: javascript, function

I encountered the following behavior:

```
> foo = {};
{}
> foo.bar = function bar() { return arguments; }
[Function: bar]
> bar()
ReferenceError: bar is not defined
    at repl:1:2
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1095:12)
```

Isn't `bar` supposed to be a function in the current scope?

Adding `[var] bar =` solves the problem:

```
> bar = foo.bar = function bar() { return arguments; }
[Function: bar]
> bar(1)
{ '0': 1 }
```

But why doesn't it work without assignment to `bar`?

Comment: it is not `bar()` but `foo.bar()` where your function resides

Comment: @Dalorzo I know, but it's not `function() {...}` but `function bar() {...}`.

Comment: to scope to `this` you need to append the function to a property on `this` not on you new object. Your new object is actually appended to `this`.

Comment: @No1_Melman I know that, but I want to add the function both to `this` and `foo` object.

Comment: Don't use `this.var` in your example, but just the global `bar` variable (to limit the confusion to named function expressions, and not include the role of the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: well then after you declare your object on foo, set your `this` property `bar` to the `foo.bar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context you are using the function keyword in (on the RHS of an assignment) makes it a [function *expression*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), not a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function).

Putting a name between `function` and `()` makes it a named function, but since it is not a function declaration it doesn't create a variable in the current scope.

Note that named function expressions have [memory leak issues](http://kiro.me/blog/nfe_dilemma.html) in old-IE.

Comment: What is a *function expression*? Is there any doc reference regarding this subject?

Comment: MDN isn't an as good ressource as [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1048572) on that question (it doesn't strictly distinguish them, and adds in Mozilla's "function statement"s)

Answer (score 1):

When you are using a function declaration of that type in that context, you are creating a *named function expression* (NFE). Contrast this with simply declaring a named function, when you have a *function declaration*.

The spec says that the name of an NFE shall only be accessible inside the function itself. Here's how to see the difference:

```
var x = function() { console.log(foo); }      // (anonymous) function expression
x(); // ReferenceError: foo is undefined

var y = function foo() { console.log(foo); }  // NFE
y(); // function foo()...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially creating what is a named function expression. And hence it is not in the current scope but is assigned to the property of the object `foo` as a method instead.

When using the `function` keyword in an expression (as opposed to a declaration) when no name is given, you create an anonymous function as you are already aware, I'm sure.

When a name is added between the `function` keyword and the `()` in the context of an expression, you are created a **named function expression**.

The scope of the name of the function is **within the function itself**, so inside the function, you may recursively call itself using `bar()` but outside, it does not exist and gives you the *ReferenceError* that you are encountering.